# SQL Server - Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with datetimeoffset

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am having issue with passing the data from one table to another due to data type. 
I tried converting datetimeoffset into date, and inserting into table where i have it as date type and im still getting this error. 
this is the format of date/time i have:
2018-12-12 13:00:00 -05:00 in one table, and i have to just pars time and insert it into new table. I tried with casting using ,

```
CAST([from] AS date) DATE_FROM
```

I can run the query as select and it works but the moment i try to insert the data into other table even if the other table is formatted and prepared as date type i still get the issue.

Here is the table that stored data with datetimeoffset:

```
[dbo].[tmp_count](
[elements_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[content_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[element_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[element-name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[sensor-type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[data-type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[from] [datetimeoffset](0) NULL,
[to] [datetimeoffset](0) NULL,
[measurements_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[measurement_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[from (1)] [datetimeoffset](0) NULL,
[to (1)] [datetimeoffset](0) NULL,
[values_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[label] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[text] [tinyint] NULL
```

And I am trying to cast columns with datetimeoffset to date and time and push it to #tmp1 table with

```
   SELECT [elements_Id]
  ,[content_Id]
  ,[element_Id]
  ,[element-name]
  ,[sensor-type]
  ,[data-type]
  ,CAST([from] AS date) DATE_FROM
  ,[to]
  ,[measurements_Id]
  ,[measurement_Id]
  ,CAST([from (1)] AS time (0)) TIME_FROM
  ,CAST([to (1)] AS TIME(0)) TIME_TO
  ,[values_Id]
  ,[label]
  ,[text]
  INTO #Tmp1
  FROM [VHA].[dbo].[tmp_count]

  SELECT 
  FROM #tmp1
```

which gives me the time in format for DATE_FROM as 2018-12-12 and for the DATE_FROM and DATE_TO as 13:00:00 which is exactly what i need.

Now i am trying to splice this table with another table and push it in final table that looks like this:

```
[dbo].[tbl_ALL_DATA_N](
[serial-number] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ip-address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[group] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[device-type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[elements_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[content_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[element_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[element-name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[sensor-type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[data-type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[DATE_FROM] [date] NULL,
[to] [datetimeoffset](0) NULL,
[measurements_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[measurement_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[TIME_FROM] [time](0) NULL,
[TIME_TO] [time](0) NULL,
[values_Id] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
[label] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[text] [tinyint] NULL
```

using query below:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_ALL_DATA_N]
        ([serial-number], 
         [ip-address], 
         [name], 
         [group], 
         [device-type], 
         [measurement_id], 
         TIME_FROM, 
         TIME_TO, 
         [content_id], 
         [elements_id], 
         [element-name], 
         [sensor-type], 
         [data-type], 
         DATE_FROM, 
         [to], 
         [element_id], 
         [measurements_id], 
         [values_id], 
         [label], 
         [text]) 
   SELECT * 
   FROM   [VHA].[dbo].[tmp_sensor_info] A 
   FULL OUTER JOIN #tmp1 B 
                ON 1 = 1
```

And here is another message im getting: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 25
Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with time

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try casting it as datetime?

Comment: What is the value of `[From]`? And, if it's a date why is it not being stored as a `date`?

Comment: That error, however, isn't representative of the error you've given us. Your SQL has the datatype `date`, but your error states `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: And we also need clarification of the data type of the source data, data type of the destination column, and the full text of the error you're receiving.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values, just like numeric types. The error complains that you tried to mix datetimeoffset and numeric columns. Most likely, `tbl_ALL_DATA_N` and `tmp_sensor_info` have a different column order and  `SELECT * 
   FROM   [VHA].[dbo].[tmp_sensor_info] A` returns data in the wrong order

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thank you for help on this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, which @PanagiotisKanavos alluded to in the comments, is to explicitly list the columns in your final `SELECT * FROM...`. The order of the columns in that `SELECT` statement aren't lining up with the columns you're `INSERT`ing into in the destination table.

You may need to run an ad hoc instance of the query to sort out the column order. And then do yourself a favor for future maintenance and be sure to include a table alias on all of the listed columns so you (or whoever has to look at the code next) can easily find out if data is coming from `[VHA].[dbo].[tmp_sensor_info]` or `#tmp1`.

This is just one of many dangers in using `SELECT *` in production code. There's a ton of discussion on the issue in this question: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Also, as long as you're in there fixing up the query, consider meaningful table aliases. See: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: this fixed the issue. Thank you for all your help and advice regarding select statement and aliases